# Is there any cost advantage of Parse.Object.saveAll vs. saving individually?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

The Parse JS SDK provides a `Parse.Object.saveAll()` method to save many objects with one command.

From looking at [`ParseServerRESTController.js`](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/14a8d333a3add3ed7a8967341e3d6535901eafa4/src/ParseServerRESTController.js#L52-L94) it seems that each object is saved individually:

```
if (path === '/batch') {
    let initialPromise = Promise.resolve();
    if (data.transaction === true) {
        initialPromise = config.database.createTransactionalSession();
    }
    return initialPromise.then(() => {
        const promises = data.requests.map(request => {
            return handleRequest(
                request.method,
                request.path,
                request.body,
                options,
                config
            ).then(
                response => {
                    return {
                        success: response
                    };
                },
                error => {
                    return {
                        error: {
                            code: error.code,
                            error: error.message
                        },
                    };
                }
            );
        });
        return Promise.all(promises).then(result => {
            if (data.transaction === true) {
                if (
                    result.find(resultItem => typeof resultItem.error === 'object')
                ) {
                    return config.database.abortTransactionalSession().then(() => {
                        return Promise.reject(result);
                    });
                } else {
                    return config.database.commitTransactionalSession().then(() => {
                        return result;
                    });
                }
            } else {
                return result;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

It seems that `saveAll` is merely a convenience wrapper around saving each object individually, so it still does seem to make `n` database requests for `n` objects.

It it correct that `saveAll` has no cost advantage (performance, network traffic, etc) vs. saving each object individually *in Cloud Code*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can tell you that the answer is that `Parse.Object.saveAll` and `Parse.Object.destroyAll` batch requests by [default](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-JS/blob/3816347902e0b15b3d2ff57a3ef058e551af82ed/src/ParseObject.js#L2166) in batches of [20](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-JS/blob/ac38333fec3bd250a89cbcb964761ff99ba3886e/src/CoreManager.js#L178)  objects. But why take my word for it?  Let's test it out!

Turn verbose logging on and then run the following:

```js
const run = async function run() {
  const objects = [...Array(10).keys()].map(i => new Parse.Object('Test').set({i}));
  await Parse.Object.saveAll(objects);

  const promises = objects.map(o => o.increment('i').save());
  return Promise.all(promises);
};

run()
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```

And here's the output from the parse-server logs (I've truncated it, but it should be enough to be apparent what is going on):

```
verbose: REQUEST for [POST] /parse/batch: { // <--- note the path
  "requests": [ // <--- an array of requests!!!
    {
      "method": "POST",
      "body": {
        "i": 0
      },
      "path": "/parse/classes/Test"
    },

    ... skip the next 7, you get the idea

    {
      "method": "POST",
      "body": {
        "i": 9
      },
      "path": "/parse/classes/Test"
    }
  ]
} 
.... // <-- remove some irrelevent output for brevity.
verbose: RESPONSE from [POST] /parse/batch: { 
  "response": [
    {
      "success": {
        "objectId": "szVkuqURVq",
        "createdAt": "2020-03-05T21:25:44.487Z"
      }
    },
    ...
    {
      "success": {
        "objectId": "D18WB4Nsra",
        "createdAt": "2020-03-05T21:25:44.491Z"
      }
    }
  ]
} 
...

// now we iterate through and there's a request per object.
verbose: REQUEST for [PUT] /parse/classes/Test/szVkuqURVq: {
  "i": {
    "__op": "Increment",
    "amount": 1
  }
} 
...
verbose: REQUEST for [PUT] /parse/classes/Test/HtIqDIsrX3: {
  "i": {
    "__op": "Increment",
    "amount": 1
  }
} 
// and the responses...
verbose: RESPONSE from [PUT] /parse/classes/Test/szVkuqURVq: {
  "response": {
    "i": 1,
    "updatedAt": "2020-03-05T21:25:44.714Z"
  }
}
...
```

In the core manager code, you do correctly identify that we are making a request for each object to the data store (i.e. MongoDB),  This is necessary because an object may have relations or pointers that have to be handled and that may require additional calls to the data store.

BUT! calls between the parse server and the data store are usually over very fast networks using a binary format, whereas calls between the client and the parse server are JSON and go over longer distances with ordinarily much slower connections.

There is one other potential advantage that you can see in the core manager code which is that the batch is done in a transaction.

Comment: Thanks, I should have mentioned that I was referring to cloud code, my bad. The focus is on data traffic and request costs between parse server and the data store. This confirms that there is not cost advantage.

Comment: Even in cloud code there will be a savings as cloud code still makes requests to parse-server!  You could prove that by putting my code into a cloud function and then calling that.

Comment: Isn't cloud code calling `localhost`? In my understanding this does not incur data traffic charges, at least on most IaaS.

Comment: You are correct that for your AWS instances, it will not incur a $ cost.  I took your question to mean cost in terms of efficiency, not necessarily just $$. :).

Comment: In what aspect would it be more efficient? I can think of some sort of request limits when calling a port of localhost, but that is outside my realm :)

Comment: more efficient in that TCP and HTTP have overhead so one request for 20 objects is more efficient than 20 requests for 1 object.  There are also some marginal efficiency savings in parse server too, for example only checking request headers once instead of 20 times.  In other words, you are using your resources more efficiently when you batch.

Comment: That makes sense, and has a $ implication as well when looking at scale.